# Ember JS - Updating / Refreshing Model data From Route Action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

This seems to be very simple problem but I can't find any solution for this. I want to refresh the data for `unprocessedDailyDataFile` from action. I can get the model by `modelFor()` method. But when I try to use `get()` and `set()` method with the model they fails as undefined.

### Code for Route

```
App.AdminRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return {
            companies: this.store.find('company'),
            unprocessedDailyDataFiles: this.store.find('unprocessedDailyDataFile')
        };
    },
    actions: {
        reloadUnprocessedDailyDataFile: function(){
            var model = this.modelFor('admin');
            // both properties from the model is accessible here
            // model.get() fails
            // model.set() fails
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just call [.reload()](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload)?

Comment: `reload()` also fails as not defined

Answer (score 1):

For the model to reload, you can use

```
actions: {
           reloadUnprocessedDailyDataFile: function(){

               let  model =  this.get('controller.model'); // for Get and Set
               model.get('name'); 
               model.set({ name: 'john'});
    }
}
```

Comment: In case If you want to Refresh your Model Manually,  Then you have to use

this.refresh( ); inside the actions method.